# How to replace a sensitivity label with protection/encryption without requesting the user’s credentials?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-information-protection

We have created a utility that scans the SharePoint document library, checks applied sensitivity labels against predefined rules and if needed it applies a new (higher label).

Everything works fine except when a label with protection/encryption is to be replaced with another label. In such a case, we can download the file, apply the new label but we get an error when trying to upload the file, saying:

```
Code: accessDenied
Message: You do not have authorization to access the file.
```

The error occurs only when the tool authenticates requesting app-only access, i.e. using *ClientID* and *ClientSecret* or a *Certificate* but it works fine when authenticated using a delegated access, i.e. on behalf of an existing user. Also replacing a label without protection/encryption works fine.

We are using **Microsoft Graph API** to download/upload files and **MIP SDK** to apply labels.

Is there any way how to replace a label with protection/encryption without requesting the user’s credentials?